# Loop Json ChainMap in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, for-loop

I have the following python objects that contained the following values. I am only interested in the values inside "parameters".

```
injury=     {
    "class" :"Distribution",
    "dtype" :"str",
    "name" :"DiscreteDistribution",
    "parameters" :[
        {
            "No" :0.9794526467893897,
            "Yes" :0.02054735321061031
        }
    ],

}
rescued=        {
    "class" :"Distribution",
    "dtype" :"str",
    "name" :"DiscreteDistribution",
    "parameters" :[
        {
            "No" :0.9966289759244428,
            "Yes" :0.0033710240755573107
        }
    ],

}
manual_system_impact=       {
    "class" :"Distribution",
    "dtype" :"str",
    "name" :"DiscreteDistribution",
    "parameters" :[
        {
            "Made incident worse" :2.5685581140811714e-05,
            "Did not contain fire" :0.9752944628959785,
            "Extinguished fire" :0.020906757015599593,
            "Contained fire" :0.0037730945072812186
        }
    ],

}
```

I am using ChainMap to print only the values inside "parameters" of each of the objects.

I am using the following loop but I only get the values inside "parameters" of the first object (injury).

```
chained_dict = ChainMap(injury, rescued, manual_system_impact)

for i in chained_dict:
    if i == 'parameters':
        print(chained_dict['parameters'])
```

Can anyone help me to have a loop that prints the values inside "parameters" of each of the three objects, please? Any other method to obtain the "parameters" is welcome, it can also be in pandas.

Comment: Why are you using `ChainMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it even not creating a list (but creating silently a tuple in the end)  :

```
for x in injury, rescued, manual_system_impact:
    print(x['parameters'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "silently"? How is this materially different than using a list?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a smart and quick approach. If I have more objects, say 30 not only three, I guess the list could work?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga silently in the sense that maybe you could't notice it, because there are no parenthesis. It is different just in the sintax, I think that maybe this notation could be nonetheless instructive.

Comment: @Karla Andrea Sandoval yes, but you can even just list them defining a variable and you would creare a tuple like this: `tup_obj = injury, rescued, manual_system_impact`But in the end It doesn't matter if you do this with lists or tuples :-)

Comment: @KarlaAndreaSandoval both approaches would be exactly the same, indeed, the compiler will optimize the literal to create a `tuple` object anyway if you don't assign the result to a variable or other reference

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I didn't really get your question cause I don't undrstand why you  don't simply use 3 prints... But maybe this help you

```
for d in [injury, rescued, manual_system_impact]:
    print(d['parameters'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put the three objects as an example. I have actually 37 objects that I have to run several times with different values. That is why I need the loop.